# SugarCRM community faststack version - share running a WP Platform together

Tags: apache, hosting, virtualhost, self-hosting

My machine already installed SugarCRM Community FastStack version.
I already open port 80, ppl outside the network able to access to the CRM, without any problem.

This is the link from outsider

```
http://crm.com/sugarcrm/index.php?
action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index
```

I went to 
C:\sugarcrm-6.2.4\apache2\conf\httpd.conf

in the last line I added

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName wp.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\sugarcrm-6.2.4\htdocs\wp"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter to wp.com, it automatic go to wp.com/sugarcrm

I have no idea why it will automatic added another /sugarcrm at behind.

This lines of code also break my crm.com <- original worked URL.

Any idea how do I configure it?

*Environment Windows XP SP3
*Port Forward port 80

Target: able to share the same apache server with wordpress hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I able to resolved this, at first I keep looking and search in the httpd.conf, see which line of the code do the redirect action, but I fail to do it. After I did some research on default redirect, I found out XXAMP also having the same problem. Then I realize is the index.html make the redirect. Here is the step to resolve it.

Step 1:
Remove index.html: C:\sugarcrm-6.2.4\htdocs\index.html
This is the main reason make the redirect action.

Step 2:
Clear your browser cache totally, and restart it. (Browser is too smart to keep redirect, if you did not clean the cache)

Add this to the httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName wp.com
        DocumentRoot "C:\sugarcrm-6.2.4\htdocs\wp"
</VirtualHost>
```

You can enjoy both hosting in 1 webserver.